# set 2nd tab as a default selected tab in MaterialTabHost android

Tags: android, material-design

I am using  to create Tabs and using viewpager with this.

Now, it is giving the tabs with first tab selected by default, but I want to show 2nd tab as selected tab in some cases.

I have used viewPager.setCurrentItem(0) function, but it's also not doing the desired work.

Please help me here, if you have any idea how can I do this with MaterialTabHost.

Thank you so much in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Order matters. Set your view pager first.

```
 viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
 setupViewPager(viewPager);

 viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);

 tab = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
 tab.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```